# Mixpanel integration on landing page not working

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I have just integrated mixpanel on my landing page to track user behavior. I put the code mixpanel gave me here :

```
 <!-- start Mixpanel --><script type="text/javascript">(function(f,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,e,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=f.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";e=f.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(a,e)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
mixpanel.init("******");</script><!-- end Mixpanel -->
</head>
```

then I wanted to test my set up by tracking a click event on my page (someone clicking on the link with `id="google_play"`, so I wrotte in my `script`tag :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          mixpanel.track("google_play_click", {
            "id": "google_play"
          });
       });
```

1) Is that the right way to track an event ?
2)when I am going on my page I ve got an error in the chrome console concerning mixpanel :

```
Remote Address:23.214.151.115:80
Request URL:http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the first argument of Mixpanel track function is the event name. Second argument is the properties you want to attach to that event. See documentation [here](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track).

Your code should look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#google_play').on('click', function () {
        mixpanel.track("button clicked", {
            "id": "google_play"
        });
    });
});
```

Or if you want something more general, you can track every element with a certain class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.track-me').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        mixpanel.track("button clicked", {
            "id": id
        });
    });
});
```

Regarding second question, make sure the code is the same as [shown here](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript) and also double check the token you are using when calling `mixpanel.init("YOUR MIXPANEL YOKEN");`